# How do I add input users in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Good evening, everybody, I am new here and of course, I am new in python coding! I want to create a program that will ask the user for 5 students name and their grades and in the end put the results in a dictionary. The code that I have written is this :

```
x=0
while x<5:
    x=x+1
    name=input("Please give me the name of a student")
    grade=float(input("Also I would like the grade of this student"))
    students={}
    students['name']=name
    students['grade']=grade
print (students)
```

The problem is that the result I get is from the last student and not all the answers from the user

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Just define `students={}` first *outside* the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be better off having a [Dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for each student, and a [List](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to hold your list of students.

As mentioned by Can you need to define your Dict or List holding the students outside of the main loop where the student details are entered.

Example Code:

```
x=0
students = []
while x<5:
    x=x+1
    name=input("Please give me the name of a student")
    grade=float(input("Also I would like the grade of this student"))
    student={}
    student['name']=name
    student['grade']=grade
    students.append(student)
print (students)
```

Comment: it worked really good, I was wondering how to combine list and dictionary and that was really helpful thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You need to define students array outside the loop. Each time you iterate in the loop, a new students array is initialized and you lose the previous students.